# Problem with /etc/sudoers

Tags: 16.04, server, sudo

I got a little problem with my `/etc/sudoers` file on a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server.
If I do a sudo with my user I always get the error:
`sudo: /etc/sudoers not a file or directory`.

- sudo is still working
- file is where it belongs to be

Its more like a style problem cause the user is in the right group and the file has the rights 0440. So everything is working but the error is still visible with every `sudo` I use

Comment: Please don't do `sudo nano /etc/sudoers` rather do `sudo visudo` else a lot might go wrong!

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified a file reader. You need to either use `visudo` or `nano` (which Ubuntu uses as default file editor for `visudo` instead of `vi`, in a totally non-confusing way).

For example:

- `sudo visudo`
- `sudo nano /etc/sudoers`

Why should you use `visudo` over other methods? Because unlike other text editors, it validates the syntax of the file upon saving, preventing potentially crippling access problems.

Comment: Please don't do `sudo nano /etc/sudoers` rather do `sudo visudo` else a lot might go wrong!

Comment: I get the point you're making, but that's really down to the user. I provided two example methods, and explained why one was preferred. I agree that best practice here would be to use `sudo visudo`, but best practice is also subjective to a users ability. Theoretically you can use any file editor, as the original question was actually regarding why the command used was not working, not why you should use one over another.

Comment: Please always give good advice, I know your trying to help but always give good advice...

Answer (score 0):

This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
 Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of directly modifying this file.

In hoping that help